# How do I serialize/deserialize &[f64] using serde in Rust?

Tags: rust, serde

This compiles successfully:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    value: f64
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let perspn = Person { name: "me".into(), value: 30_f64};
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&perspn).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", serialized);
    Ok(())
}
```

But on changing a member of the struct to &[f64], then compilation fails

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Person<'a> {
    name: String,
    value: &'a[f64]
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let perspn = Person { name: "me".into(), value: &[30_f64]};
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&perspn).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", serialized);
    Ok(())
}
```

fails with error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&[f64]: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:168:5
    |
168 |     value: &'a[f64]
    |     ^^^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `&[f64]`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserialize<'de>`:
              &'a [u8]
              [T; 0]
              [T; 10]
              [T; 11]
              [T; 12]
              [T; 13]
              [T; 14]
              [T; 15]
            and 26 others
```

Why is this? Why does serde have a default deserialiser for `f64` but not for `&[f64]`?

Looking at the error it looks like it is only `[u8]` that serde can handle by default. Why is this?

Now the question is, how do I deserialize `&[f64]`? I know I will need to write a custom deserializer for it, but given that a custom one was not given, I am wondering if there are edge case in the implementation that made that the case and which I need to be aware of?

Comment: It's not about serialization, but deserialization (note "the trait bound *Deserialize* is not satisfied"). Serde can not deserialize and produce a slice, because where does the data that the slice points to would live?

Comment: In fact, if you only want to serialize, it works perfectly ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5de8eaf35e082c31ffa9a9e4f087c74a)).

Comment: @justinas that false serde can deserialize into a slice, but not a slice of f64, you can do this with a slice of u8

Comment: @justinas fixed the typo in the question.

Comment: @justinas for my use case I actually need the deserilization to work, and like Stargateur pointed out, this works with slide of u8 but not slice of f64. Not sure why that is the case

Comment: I agree with @justinas on this one: *someone* needs to own the slice if you want to have a borrow of it.

Comment: the borrow is not the problem serde can deserialize by borrowing the original data, but while it's easy to do this for octet (u8) it's not for f64, not all format could reuse original data and yield f64 usable by Rust so you need a Vec<f64> for f64.

Comment: That kinda makes sense. For my use case I have switched to Vec<f64> and everything works fine. Just not sure now why it worked for &[u8]

Comment: `&[u8]` works (only in some cases - e.g. not when escape sequences are present) because serde can just reference a portion of the original JSON document: strings are, after all, sequences of bytes. However, no sequence `f64` exists in memory that serde can point the slice to - the floats need to get parsed from string representation and stored somewhere.